# Java Web Communications Without Port Forwarding

Tags: java, client, p2p

I wish to make a program in which two clients will connect to each other and one of the clients will host the server... both clients should be able to connect to the server... Is there a way to do this without port forwarding... Some kind of peer to peer system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the simple solution is T.U.R.N., where all communication passes through the server (Peer A <-> Server <-> Peer B). The server has to have a public IP address to be reachable from the anywhere on the net.

Peers should initiate and keep 'alive' TCP connections to the server.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you are looking for RMI.